# Automating third party iOS and Android apps

Tags: automation

I am working on a project that requires accessing third party apps (iOS and android) to check if they are accessible on a user's device while the internet is being routed through a specific proxy. The proxy controls what the user can/cannot access. The real challenge is i am required to test this every time a new version of the app is released and whenever the proxy is updated. At the moment, this purely a manual testing activity but i am just curious to know if i can automate this process on a real device and have a few checkpoints that can tell me if my tests have passed/failed. Any suggestions?